# % and/or format for function string

Tags: python, string, function

I'm using format to test a function in Python.  I would like the output of a function

```
def test(f,k):
    print "{0}({1})={2}".format(f,k,f(k))
```

given

```
test(Sqrt,4)
```

to be

```
Sqrt(4)=2
```

But format is giving back the type 'function' and a memory address inside angle braces.  Is there a neat way to shorten the output to get what I'm after?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking to use `__name__`:

```
def test(f,k):
    print("{0}({1})={2}".format(f.__name__,k,f(k)))

test(sqrt, 2)
```

Output:

```
sqrt(2)=1.4142135623730951
```

From the "Callable types" section of the Data Model docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#data-model) , `__name__` is simply:

```
__name__ func_name : The function’s name.
```

Read the documentation carefully to understand *what* is available to you when wanting to use these types of attributes. Typically, this will be available to *callable* types (e.g. when defining a method or class, the  `__name__` attribute will be available to you). But if you simply define a non-callable, something like:

```
x = 5
```

and try to call `x.__name__`, you will be met with an `AttributeError`

Answer (score 2):

Unlike most objects in Python, functions have a `__name__` attribute set to the name they were defined with. You could use that:

```
print "{0}({1})={2}".format(f.__name__, k, f(k))
```

Classes also have a `__name__`, but most other callables don't. If `f` is some other kind of callable, you'll have to deal with it differently, in a manner that will depend on what kind of callable it is and whether you control its implementation.